# How do I remove the Downloads option from Disk Cleanup?

Tags: windows-10, disk-cleanup, windows-10-v1809

In the new Windows 10 October 2018 Update, the Disk Cleanup tool (yes, I know, soon to be deprecated) has a new option to delete one's Downloads folder, in addition to the other options for cleanup.

However, I use the Downloads folder of my system for storage, rather than just as a temporary folder. If I accidentally check that box the next time I use the tool, I run the risk of deleting files important to me.

How can I remove that option from Disk Cleanup, so that there's no risk of me accidentally checking that box and accidentally deleting personal files?

Comment: You cannot modify the Disk Cleanup, but you can disable its popping up in a reversible way.

Comment: The option cannot be removed but it will only be enabled if you enable it

Comment: @Ramhound The point of this question is, I don't want to enable it by accident.

Comment: @gparyani - What you want isn’t possible unless you revert to a version of Windows 10 that doesn’t have the option.  However, that isn’t a permanent solution, since eventually you will have to upgrade in order to receive security updates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Create a System Restore Point.
2. Start the Registry Editor (`regedit.exe`)
3. Go to the following branch:

   > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches\DownloadsFolder
4. Right-click on the `DownloadsFolder` key, click `Export` and save the branch to
   a REG file.
5. Right-click on the `DownloadsFolder` key, and choose Delete.
6. Quit the Registry Editor.

The `Downloads` option should now be gone from Disk Cleanup.
[image]